# Moving a tick mark horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have asked about moving a tick mark from below the x-axis to above the x-axis.  (I used the specification `xticklabel shift=-16pt.`)  In the following graph, the tick mark is at a point where the graph has a horizontal asymptote.  I need to move the tick mark 2pt either to the left or to the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,unit vector ratio={2 1},clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-1.5,xmax=2.5,
    domain=-1.5:2.5, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-1,ymax=3,
    restrict y to domain=-1:3,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={0.83333, 1, 1.6666},
    extra x tick labels={$\frac{5}{6}$, $1$, $\frac{5}{3}$},
    extra y ticks={-2},
    extra y tick labels={$ma+b$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    yticklabel shift=-4pt,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={0.83333, 1, 1.6666},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-1.5:1,blue] {-1* x * abs((x - 1))^(1/5)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=1:4,blue] {x * abs((x - 1))^(1/5)} node[below right,pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$y=f(x)$};
\draw [fill] (0.83333,-0.58236) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (1.6666,1.53685) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `ticklabel style={xshift=2pt,font=\tiny,fill=white},` Note xshift.  If you want it only for `xtick`s, use a separate `xticklabel style`

Comment: Related Question: [Moving a tick mark on each axis but keeping the default tick marks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210586/moving-a-tick-mark-on-each-axis-but-keeping-the-default-tick-marks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want to move *one* tick mark, it is best to simply tweak it with a bit of a space. So something like

```
extra x tick labels={$\frac{5}{6}$, \hspace*{0.5em}$1$, $\frac{5}{3}$}
```

yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,unit vector ratio={2 1},clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-1.5,xmax=2.5,
    domain=-1.5:2.5, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-1,ymax=3,
    restrict y to domain=-1:3,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    %xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    extra x ticks={0.83333, 1, 1.6666},
    extra x tick labels={$\frac{5}{6}$, \hspace*{0.5em}$1$, $\frac{5}{3}$},
    extra y ticks={-2},
    extra y tick labels={$ma+b$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=west},
    yticklabel shift=-4pt,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={0.83333, 1, 1.6666},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-1.5:1,blue] {-1* x * abs((x - 1))^(1/5)};
\addplot[samples=501,domain=1:4,blue] {x * abs((x - 1))^(1/5)} node[below right,pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$y=f(x)$};
\draw [fill] (0.83333,-0.58236) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] (1.6666,1.53685) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again.  You just put a spacing command from text mode before the label for the tick mark.  Do you have to use the *-version of the space command?  Did TikZ really move it half the width of "M"?

Comment: The `*` variant ensures the space is added even at the beginning of the line. I did not test if it works without the `*`. Yes, the space is intended to be _approximately_ half the width of an `m`, accounting for the fact that font size of the `ticklabel`.

Comment: I have a question that is not relevant to this post.  Do you know the length of each side of the right angle mark in this drawing? I have a diagram of right triangles that are drawn using tkz-euclide on another page; I want the right-angle marks that I have to manually make in this diagram to be identical to the right angle marks drawn by TikZ.

Comment: @Adelyn: As that is totally unrelated to this question, please post a new question. That way it will be helpful to a larger audience.

Comment: I just posted it.  "Getting the same angle marks using pgfplots as those using TikZ"