# Single ytick label not moving

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, automata, positioning, matrix, calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        width = 5 in,
        height = 2.5 in,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1.5, 3, 4.5, 6},
        xticklabels={$\frac{T}{2}$, $T$, $\frac{3T}{2}$, $2T$},
        ytick={-0.5, 0.5},
        yticklabels={\vspace*{1cm}$-0.5$,  $0.5$},
        %extra x ticks = {0},
        %xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5,
        %           extra y ticks = {0},
        xmin=-1,xmax=7.5,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->, xlabel = {$t$}, ylabel={$V_\textrm{in}$ ($\SI{}{\volt}$)},
        %every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},
        %every axis x label/.style={at={(1,2/3)},anchor=west},
        xticklabel style = {xshift=-0.35cm},
        every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,},
        domain=-pi:pi,samples=101]
        \addplot [blue,thick]coordinates
        {(-1,-0.5) (0,-0.5) (0,0.5) (1.5,0.5) (1.5,-0.5) (3,-0.5) (3,0.5) (4.5, 0.5) (4.5, -0.5) (6, -0.5) (6, 0.5) (7.5, 0.5)};
        \node at(axis cs:0.75,0.25) {Region 1};
        \node at(axis cs:2.25,-0.25) {Region 2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{Square wave input.}
        \label{SqIn}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

I am trying to move the `yticklabel` `-0.5` down, but it is not. I even tried the solution on [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209683/moving-a-tick-mark-horizontally), but it didn't work as well.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the style of the y tick labels depend on `\ticknum`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        width = 5 in,
        height = 2.5 in,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1.5, 3, 4.5, 6},
        xticklabels={$\frac{T}{2}$, $T$, $\frac{3T}{2}$, $2T$},
        ytick={-0.5, 0.5},
        yticklabels={$-0.5$,  $0.5$},
        yticklabel style={yshift=1em-\ticknum*1em},
        %extra x ticks = {0},
        %xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5,
        %           extra y ticks = {0},
        xmin=-1,xmax=7.5,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->, xlabel = {$t$}, ylabel={$V_\textrm{in}$ ($\SI{}{\volt}$)},
        %every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},
        %every axis x label/.style={at={(1,2/3)},anchor=west},
        xticklabel style = {xshift=-0.35cm},
        every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,},
        domain=-pi:pi,samples=101]
        \addplot [blue,thick]coordinates
        {(-1,-0.5) (0,-0.5) (0,0.5) (1.5,0.5) (1.5,-0.5) (3,-0.5) (3,0.5) (4.5, 0.5) (4.5, -0.5) (6, -0.5) (6, 0.5) (7.5, 0.5)};
        \node at(axis cs:0.75,0.25) {Region 1};
        \node at(axis cs:2.25,-0.25) {Region 2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{Square wave input.}
        \label{SqIn}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively one can play with `extra y ticks` as in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        width = 5 in,
        height = 2.5 in,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1.5, 3, 4.5, 6},
        xticklabels={$\frac{T}{2}$, $T$, $\frac{3T}{2}$, $2T$},
        ytick={0.5},
        yticklabels={$0.5$},
        extra y ticks={-0.5},
        every extra y tick/.style={yshift=1em},
        %extra x ticks = {0},
        %xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5,
        %           extra y ticks = {0},
        xmin=-1,xmax=7.5,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->, xlabel = {$t$}, ylabel={$V_\textrm{in}$ ($\SI{}{\volt}$)},
        %every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},
        %every axis x label/.style={at={(1,2/3)},anchor=west},
        xticklabel style = {xshift=-0.35cm},
        every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,},
        domain=-pi:pi,samples=101]
        \addplot [blue,thick]coordinates
        {(-1,-0.5) (0,-0.5) (0,0.5) (1.5,0.5) (1.5,-0.5) (3,-0.5) (3,0.5) (4.5, 0.5) (4.5, -0.5) (6, -0.5) (6, 0.5) (7.5, 0.5)};
        \node at(axis cs:0.75,0.25) {Region 1};
        \node at(axis cs:2.25,-0.25) {Region 2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{Square wave input.}
        \label{SqIn}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which yields the same result. `\ticknum` is the number/index of the tick. he first one has `\ticknum=0`, the second one `\ticknum=1` and so on. One can thus introduce an alternating alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{figure}[H]\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        width = 5 in,
        height = 2.5 in,
        scale only axis,
        xtick={1.5, 3, 4.5, 6},
        xticklabels={$\frac{T}{2}$, $T$, $\frac{3T}{2}$, $2T$},
        ytick={-0.5, 0.5},
        yticklabels={$-0.5$,  $0.5$},
        yticklabel style={anchor=180+\ticknum*180},
        %extra x ticks = {0},
        %xmin=-0.5,xmax=7.5,
        %           extra y ticks = {0},
        xmin=-1,xmax=7.5,
        ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->, xlabel = {$t$}, ylabel={$V_\textrm{in}$ ($\SI{}{\volt}$)},
        %every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},anchor=south},
        %every axis x label/.style={at={(1,2/3)},anchor=west},
        xticklabel style = {xshift=-0.35cm},
        every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=south,},
        domain=-pi:pi,samples=101]
        \addplot [blue,thick]coordinates
        {(-1,-0.5) (0,-0.5) (0,0.5) (1.5,0.5) (1.5,-0.5) (3,-0.5) (3,0.5) (4.5, 0.5) (4.5, -0.5) (6, -0.5) (6, 0.5) (7.5, 0.5)};
        \node at(axis cs:0.75,0.25) {Region 1};
        \node at(axis cs:2.25,-0.25) {Region 2};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption{Square wave input.}
        \label{SqIn}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does `yticklabel style={yshift=1em-\ticknum*1em},` do? How does one know what `\ticknum` is?

Comment: I actually tried `extra y tick`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @Superman `\ticknum` is the number/index of the trick. The first one has `\ticknum=0`, the second one `\ticknum=1` and so on. I like this method because you can implement rules for odd vs. even `\ticknum` etc. (Since I do not know how you used `extra y ticks` I cannot tell you what went wrong, perhaps only `extra y ticks` vs. `extra y tick`, i.e. above I forgot an `s`.)

Comment: Oh hmm. So does the command `yticklabel style={yshift=1em-\ticknum*1em}` apply to *all* the ticks (except the top one doesn't get affected)?

Comment: @Superman It gets applied to all of them. Since there are only two of them, I added this simple rule. I also added an  `extra y ticks` version.

Comment: The `\ticknum` technique is quite clever. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 yticklabels={\raisebox{-1cm}{$-0.5$},  $0.5$}
```

[image]